Simplify single shape in Illustrator to remove overlapping
I have a shape in SVG format for a logo from a non-Illustrator source. In Illustrator this is a single <Compound Path>. This is not multiple paths to merge which I know how to do and plenty of info on but a single path how do I simplify? Pathfinder tools wont work since its a single object. The actual "simplify" tool seems to "simplify" the edges (like making the tips of the K into oval like shapes).


Turning 12 points to and 12 edges into 12 points and 12 edges is not really any simpler. Whether one or other is simpler depend on what you want to do. So for example if you want to animate this it may be simpler that its 3 separate islands. Likewise if you want to be able to change the thickness of the shape, or adjust the letter it may be simpler. You dont actually need to do anything other than change filling rule and they both behave the same way.

You don't really need to release the compound shape, or use Pathfinder.
Just grab the Shape Builder Tool and click-drag across the parts to combine them. This will work whether it's a compound shape or not.

(Above is a compound shape.)

Thank you! This gif was incredibly helpful. Ive used illustrator for a long time and ive never had to use this tool before. Thank you!

It's not called "simplify". You want to unite the pieces. Simplify is used for removing extra anchors on a shape that has too many anchors.
Here are two possible methods:
Select the object, then click and drag with the Shape Builder tool over the shapes to unite them.
or
Do Object > Compound Path > Release, then use the Unite button  in the Path Finder

You do actually need Pathfinder for this, and this has nothing to do with the Simplify tool.
You have 3 objects in the image, but since this comes from SVG, the objects are probably grouped and/or compounded.
So, you first need to separate the 3 objects using the "Release Compound Path" and/or "Ungroup" options, at which point the 3 objects become separated from the group.
Then, you select the 3 objects and, with these selected, click Unite in the Pathfinder panel, and you get a single shape.



